# module IO in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to `node.js` and trying to figure out how to write a module and use it in another file.

This is the module which I wrote to list the files according to the extension of files.

input : directory and extension of file.

**module** : `module_import.js`

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = function (dir, filterStr, callback) {
  fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err)
    }

    list = list.filter(function (file) {
      return path.extname(file) === '.' + filterStr
    })

    callback(null, list)
  })
}
```

`module.js` (the file in which `module_import.js` has been imported.)

```
var filterfile = require('./module_import.js');
var dir = process.argv[2];
var ext = process.argv[3];

 filterfile(dir,ext,function(err,list){
    if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }
    list.forEach(function(file){
        console.log(file);
    })
 });
```

When I run it on console by this **command** : `node module.js \dir\path\to\files .ext`

I don't get any output on the console.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `console.log(process.argv)` to help figure out what the node.js process is actually receiving when you pass command-line arguments. Bash and CMD do a step of serialization that sometimes causes unexpected behavior to the values you end up receiving, so make sure you're escaping special characters like the backslash properly.

Comment: It worked . It was an issue of whitespaces only. I was breaking my head over it from an hour. Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is to use debugging to find out what the problem is: Start your script with the `--inspect-brk` option: `node --inspect-brk yourscriptjs`, then in Chrome go to `chrome://inspect` and pick the script from the list. You're now able to single-step through your code, inspect variables, etc. (You need a fairly recent version of Node. V8.x has it, V6.x doesn't.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's really cool! Didn't know about that, I'm gonna try that sometime

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds a leading period before the filter string (representing the extension you pass from the command line):

```
return path.extname(file) === '.' + filterStr
                              ^^^
```

However, you're also passing it an extension that is preceded with a period:

```
node module.js \dir\path\to\files .ext
                                  ^
```

This will make the code try to match `..ext` (two leading periods), which will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Well can you check what you may be getting in process.argv[3]

moreover the issue you will be facing is with the part

```
  list = list.filter(function (file) {
      return path.extname(file) === '.' + filterStr
    });
```

you must have checked or gave values for process.argv[3] in the question